# Is it possible to resize the Kivy virtual keyboard?

Tags: kivy

I am using an RPI and I just changed the kivy configuration file:
"keyboard_mode = multi"

Each time I click on a text box, the kivy vkeyboard pops up but it's width is larger than my screen

Is there a way to reduce its size ?[image: kivy virtual keyboard bigger than screen width]

Comment: Never needed to resize but it seems to be resizable, being a widget.

Comment: Thank you for replying @ApuCoder
Right now it does need to be resized because apart of the virtual keyboard is cut off. The part that is cut off includes the X to close the keyboard.

I figured out something and I'll post it in the Answer section shortly

Answer (score 0):

I changed the kivy configuration file: "keyboard_mode = docked"
[image]